# How can secure AWS streaming video file hls(.ts) file or child playlist file using AWS sign cookie?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cookies, sign

I have secured mainstreaming content files like .m3u8 with secure parameters but child playlist files like .ts file I can't secure because it's run from UI console using video js player automatically. I can't handle this .ts file URL and video js directly send the request to AWS for access .ts file but without secure not run the steaming. Please, anyone, help me & provide me better suggestions to solve the issue.

Mainstreaming secure file: https://{cluodfront_url}/hls/sample_1920x1080.m3u8?Policy={policy}&Signature={signature}&Key-Pair-Id={keypair_id}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.